# Trouble deserializing rather simple JSON data using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have problem with deserializing some JSON data which looks like this:

```
{
    "Var1": 0,
    "Var2": 2,
    "Var3": -1,
    "Var4": 5,
    "Var5": 1,
    "Var6": 3
}
```

This is located on a remote server and I fetch it then deserialize using this method in a separate class:

```
public static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>() where T : new()
{
    using (var w = new WebClient())
    {
        var json_data = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            json_data = w.DownloadString("http://url_to_json_data.json");
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
    }
}
```

My JSON class:

```
public class Variables
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    public int Var2 { get; set; }
    public int Var3 { get; set; }
    public int Var4 { get; set; }
    public int Var5 { get; set; }
    public int Var6 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a different class when I need to access the data, I do this:

```
List<JsonClass.Variables> VARS = JsonClass._download_serialized_json_data<List<JsonClass.Variables>>();

System.Console.WriteLine("Variable 1: " + VARS[0].Var1);
```

And in the last part I get a massive exception thrown in my face saying this:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Solution1.JsonClass+Variables]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

How would I properly access those simple integers without overdoing the thing? I tried dictionaries but that didn't work out too well.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The sample data you have given is not an array, just one instance of the class. Are you sure it is an array (List)?

Comment: Looking at your examples the JSON only contains one object, not an array of objects so the generic argument for your download-method should be JsonClass.Variables, not List<JsonClass.Variables>.

Comment: The whole file is exactly what I have posted there. It doesnt contain the [ ] array brackets. Only { and }.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
JsonClass.Variables VARS = JsonClass._download_serialized_json_data<JsonClass.Variables>();

System.Console.WriteLine("Variable 1: " + VARS.Var1);
```

You're original code was expecting to deserialize a list of `JsonClass.Variables`, but your example JSON only has a single object.